# vba .find how to make it work

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make this VBA code work. I have never learned VBA codes but with help of google and You guys, I found some answers and my other codes works.
In this one I have a problem.
I used in this code twice .find. For first one it works and for second it doesn't. When I debug I see that it has correct column letter and it has correct value of "czas1" but somehow it can't find it in column "kolumnaletter".
Do You have any idea why?

```
Sub uzpwyniki()
Dim n As String
Dim nrOs As String
Dim nrkolOS As Range
Dim nrli As Range
Dim czas1
Dim pelne As String
Dim kolumna As String, kolumnaLetter As String
Dim z As String
nrOs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Wyniki").Range("A1")
czas1 = 0
z = 3
Set nrkolOS = Sheets("Dane").Rows("1").Find(what:=(nrOs), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
kolumna = nrkolOS.Column
kolumnaLetter = Chr(kolumna + 64)
Do While Worksheets("Wyniki").Cells(z, 4).Value <> ""
  czas1 = Worksheets("Wyniki").Cells(z, 4).Value
  Sheets("Dane").Select
  Set nrli = Sheets("Dane").Columns(kolumnaLetter).Find(what:=(czas1), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
  Worksheets("Dane").Cells(nrli.Row, 2).Select
  Worksheets("Dane").Cells(nrli.Row, 2).Copy
  Worksheets("Wyniki").Cells(z, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
  Sheets("Główna").Select
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  z = z + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no need to turn the column number into a letter.  Columns will use the index number.  Change `Set nrli = Sheets("Dane").Columns(kolumnaLetter)...` to `Set nrli = Sheets("Dane").Columns(kolumna)...`

Comment: You also have z declared as a string even though you use it as an integer.